# Getting value from stored procedure in another stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Sorry, lots of code coming up..

I saw another question like this that used output parameters. I'm using the RETURN statement to return the value I want to use.

I have one stored procedure InsertMessage that looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertNewMessage

    (
    @messageText text,
    @dateTime DATETIME,
    @byEmail bit,
    @bySMS bit
    )

AS
    DECLARE @NewId int
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO MessageSet VALUES (@byEmail, @bySMS, @dateTime, @messageText)
    SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    COMMIT
    END

    RETURN @NewId
```

which another stored procedure uses:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertMessageFromUserToGroup

    (
    @userEmail nvarchar(256),
    @groupId int,
    @messageText text,

    @bySMS bit,
    @byEmail bit
    )

AS
    --Inserts a new message to a group
    DECLARE @messageId int
    DECLARE @dateTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
    --First check if user is a part of the group
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT userEmail FROM UserToGroupSet WHERE userEmail = @userEmail AND groupId = @groupId)
        RETURN 'User not part of group'
    ELSE --User is a part of the group, add message
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            SET @messageId = [dbo].[InsertNewMessage](@messageText, @dateTime, @bySMS, @byEmail)
            INSERT INTO MessageToUser VALUES(@userEmail, @messageId)
            INSERT INTO MessageToGroup VALUES(@messageId, @groupId)
        COMMIT
    END
```

The row that causes the trouble and of which I'm unsure how to handle is this one:

```
SET @messageId = [dbo].[InsertNewMessage](@messageText, @dateTime, @bySMS, @byEmail)
```

The syntax seems ok because I can save it. When I run it I get the error message:

```
Running [dbo].[InsertMessageFromUserToGroup] ( @userEmail = test@test.com, @groupId = 5, @messageText = sdfsdf, @bySMS = false, @byEmail = true ).

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.InsertNewMessage", or the name is ambiguous.
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 
Finished running [dbo].[InsertMessageFromUserToGroup].
```

It seems as if the other stored procedure can't be found. I've tried different ways of calling the procedure but everything else fails as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

```
SET @messageId = [dbo].[InsertNewMessage](@messageText, @dateTime, @bySMS, 
    @byEmail)
```

to

```
EXEC @messageId = [dbo].[InsertNewMessage] @messageText, @dateTime, @bySMS,
     @byEmail
```

Notice that `SET` has been changed to `EXEC`, and the parentheses have been removed from the parameters.

See the example in the [MSDN documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28SQL.80%29.aspx) at the end of the article for more information.